# Is there any way that we can create an export button that ask user download route and filename in AntD

Tags: antd

I just started to use Antd framework. I need an export button that it propt user to save it a route and filename.
Is there any way to make it?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You could use either

1. [Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal/) or
2. [Popover](https://ant.design/components/popover/#header)

imo both of them are suitable for that kind of task